# Python sending many sms via usb serial

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, sms

I'm really lost now  at this part where I need to send sms to multiple recipients.

How do i send an sms to all the contacts i have in my database? Do I use for-loops? Or is there other ways? Please help thank you so much.

This is my SMS code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
import time
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb

try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    print 'Database connected';
except Exception as e:
    sys.exit('Database connection failed')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("Select contacts from dbtable")
con.commit()
number= cur.fetchall()
print number

for item in number:
    recipient= recipient+item

class TextMessage:
    def __init__(self, recipient="xxxxxxxx",message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def setRecipient(self, number):
        self.recipient = number

    def setContent(self, message):
        self.content = message

    def connectPhone(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSBSMS', 460800, timeout=5, xonxoff = False, rtscts = False, bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
        time.sleep(1)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(1)
     def disconnectPhone(self):
        self.ser.close()

sms = TextMessage("xxxxxxxx","Important!")
sms.connectPhone()
sms.sendMessage()
sms.disconnectPhone()
print "message sent successfully"
```

The printed output

```
(('99876545',), ('87546412',), ('97789546',), ('87546464',), ('97377454',))
```

Comment: Please decide which coding you want to use since it does not make sense to specify more than one. I would suggest using UTF-8 for the sake of compatability. See [PEP0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for further details.

Comment: Okay will note that thanks

Comment: After reading your question several times: What exactly is your question? Could you please provide a anonymised snippet illustrating what the Database-Server returns on your `.fetchall()` since the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) are telling that this is a list of tuples.

Comment: Yeah it is tuples.. I want to be able to send to many recipients as this code is originally for one number.. I'll put the snipplet when I reach school..

Comment: Hi, I've added the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `for` loop would do the job:

```
t_list =  (('99876545',), ('87546412',), ('97789546',), ('87546464',), ('97377454',))

for t in t_list:
    number = t[0]
    print(number)
    # Call function to send SMS to the given `number`
```

Just adapt this basic approach do fulfill your needs.

Comment: number=t[0] meaning only sending to the first number?

Comment: `('99876545',)` is a so called tuple. We can access the tuple's first element, in this case the number `99876545`, by indexing the tuple like `t[0]`. By doing this in a loop iterating through the list containing all tuples and calling the desired function to send a SMS to the number read from the tuple we are able to send a message to all recipients one after another. You should take a look at the docs about for-loops, tuples and lists.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tyra: If I you could answer your question please accept my answer in order to mark your question as closed/answered.